# Not able to login as sudo in Unix, "sudo : must be setuid root"

Tags: unix, permissions

Today I did a crazy thing: I changed the permissions for all files/folders under `/usr/bin/` as 777. Read, write and execute. Since then I am not able to login as `sudo`. It simply throws

> sudo : must be setuid root

I read in a post:

> Reboot the computer,choose recovery console and type the following
>   commands
>
> ```
> chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
> chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
> ```
>
> Reboot the machine.

But the problem is that I am not able to login as sudo to reboot. For rebooting, the user has to be a superuser, e.g. `root`. Neither do I know the password for sudo. Is there any any way I can solve this?

Comment: Please mention your OS. Have you tried to `su` using root's password?

Comment: Also, how is it possible for you to change `/usr/bin` to `777` without knowing a sudo password?

Comment: can you post what output you get with "ls -l /usr/bin/sudo"

Comment: @ Daniel Beck : the OS is linux..yes i did try su -i, but I dont know the password  @slhck 29 : first i logged in with my user and then did sudo su..it asked for my user's password and thus i logged in as sudo..but only after changing the permission, I am not not able to login as sudo...@Stephen Martin : the machine is located elsewhere and its a remote login..

Comment: I suggest you request support from the server administrators or other support staff on site. If it were possible to do this remotely, with neither `sudo` nor the root password, it'd be a serious security problem. The only way to do this yourself is to exploit security vulnerabilities like other setuid binaries, scripts that are executed as `root` on a schedule and which you can edit, etc.

Comment: @stevesam Putting a space between "@" & the username will result in the user not getting the notification

Comment: You need to understand that __there is no such thing as a sudo user__. If you need temporary root privileges as your normal user, you use `sudo` (superuserdo) and provide your user's password to run a command as `root`. To __login__ as `root` use `su` and provide the password to the `root` user.

Answer (score 1):

### The superuser is probably taking you (and `/bin/su`) out of `/etc/sudoers` (and probably `/etc/passwd`) as I type this.

If you don't know the superuser password, in order to switch to the superuser account using `/bin/su`, then *you obviously aren't the actual superuser* and that is someone else.  **The person to fix this is the actual superuser**, because you've opened a massive security hole and created a right mess.  The actual superuser, upon seeing this mess, has probably gone into BOFH mode and is busy removing your ability to ever again run things under the aegis of the superuser account, given what happens when you do.

Basically, you've opened a window where anyone with an account on the machine can compromise it and gain superuser privileges almost trivially easily.  (Some executables regularly run under the aegis of the superuser account, in response to `cron` jobs and the like, are now world-writable.)  Tidying this up *safely* is a whole lot of work, because one has to work on the basis that any executable anywhere on the system is potentially compromised by now.  Anyone who could remotely log in to an account on the machine via SSH, or exploit any other means of gaining shell access as an ordinary user, could have compromised it.

Your two-liner from an unnamed post on a discussion forum is entirely missing the security ramifications of what you've done.  But that is in part because *it addresses a different situation*.  The posts you are no doubt looking at are where people have changed the ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo`, and *have not made it world-writable like you have*.

Your superuser, if xe knows xyr stuff, will not miss the security ramifications.  But xe won't be happy with how much work you've just created for xem.

### For the poor superuser's benefit:

- https://serverfault.com/q/221447/46453